# How can I get Firebase authentication on initialization with React.js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

In my `_app.tsx` file, I have:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                // No user is signed in.
                if (router.pathname.startsWith('/app')) {
                    router.push('/');
                }
            } else {
                router.push('/app');
            }
        });
    }, []);
```

But the problem is that it always redirects to `/app` on refresh. Any way to wait to see if auth is initialized?

Comment: put a `console.log(user` as the first line inside `async (user`, this way you know if the user is ever going to be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useEffect in React.js does not support Async functions, instead you want to handle it with either callbacks or wrap it inside an async block and update it's state through a state manager like redis.

```js
useEffect( () => {
  let initiate = async () => {
   // onAuthStateChanged goes here
  }

  initiate ();
}, []);
```